# How to calculate the age of the stage field when it changes from one stage to another stage on the opportunity

Tags: apex, opportunity, formula-field

Can any one help me out .

I have a requirement where i need to calculate the age of each stage when their change from one stage to another stage .

For Example :

> I have two stages say as Stage 1 --ABC ,Stage 2 -- XYZ .
>        I Create a record  named as opp stage 1 ,with stage1 -ABC on 15th JAN and now the other users changes the stage level from ABC to XYZ on
>   say date as 20th JAN 2016.SO now i would like to calculate the age of
>   the stage 1 ...how many days it stayed .Similarly when i change from
>   stage 2 to stage 3 ...what is the duration of the stage2 stayed .

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: you need some extra fields here and populate them using trigger when you update stageName.

Comment: How do you want to show it? There are couple of options. You can even make use of the report.

Comment: @TusharSharma,@ShaileshPatil:Thanks for ur response.Can u plz help me out with an example.Im looking in configuration which easier.

Answer (score 2):

Enable **Opportunity Field History Tracking** in Salesforce. Salesforce track changes natively so, you don't need build something to track changes. You can query Opportunity Stage changes as:

```
 List<OpportunityFieldHistory> oppHistory = [Select Id, CreatedDate,
 Field, NewValue, OldValue from OpportunityFieldHistory Where Field = 'StageName'];
```

This way you will have complete visibility to stage changes. You can build your logic over it.

If you want to query through `Opportunity` instead of `OpportunityFieldHistory` then query would be:-

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT id,
        (SELECT StageName FROM OpportunityHistories) 
        FROM Opportunity];

List<OpportunityHistory> histories = oppList.OpportunityHistories;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible without trigger but for that you need to create 4 fields and 3 workflow :

Like :

1. create a **boolean** field say `isUpdate`
2. create a **date** field say `previous value`
3. create a **date** field say `new value`
4. create a **formula(Number)** field say `time spend` which is `new_value__c - previous_value__c`

and now create **workflows** :

1. workflow for record creation **Evaluation Criteria** : `when a record is created` and **Rule Criteria** : `isUpdate= false` and on this **workflow action**     ......**Field to Update**    : `Opportunity: previous_value__c` and checked the **radio** buttion `Use a formula to set the new value` and **insert field** `CreatedDate`.
2. workflow for record updation **Evaluation Criteria** : `when a record is created, and every time it’s edited` and **Rule Criteria** : `ISCHANGED( isUpdate)` and on this **workflow action** .... **Field to Update**    : `Opportunity: previous_value__c` and checked the **radio** buttion `Use a formula to set the new value` and **insert field** `new_value__c`.
3. workflow for stage updation **Evaluation Criteria** : `when a record is created, and every time it’s edited` and **Rule creteria** :  `ISCHANGED( StageName)` and on this there is 3 **workflow action** which is :

   1. **Field to Update**   : `Opportunity: new_value__c` and checked the **radio** buttion `Use a formula to set the new value` and **insert field** `LastModifiedDate`.
   2. **Field to Update**   : `Opportunity: isUpdate` and checked `true` in `Checkbox Options` .
   3. **Field to Update**   : `Opportunity: previous_value__c` and checked the **radio** buttion `Use a formula to set the new value` and **insert field** `new_value__c`.

That's all :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track by your own just create a textArea field and store all information in that with the help of trigger.
each value store formate in text Area

```
Stage1ABC#sd=12/12/2015#ed=2/03/2016#age=0,

sd is startDate,
ed is endDate,
age is the picklist val AGE,
'#' is the value separator
',' is Picklist value separator
```

Trigger for this implementation

```
trigger ageCalculator on TestObject__c (before insert, before update) {

    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(TestObject__c obj : trigger.new){                        
                obj.txtAreaval__c = obj.Stages__c+'#sd='+system.now()+ '#ed='+' #'+'age=0,';                              
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        for(TestObject__c obj : trigger.new){
                String oldpickListVal = trigger.oldMap.get(obj.id).Stages__c;

                string picklistvalDetail = oldpickListVal+''+obj.txtAreaval__c.substringBetween(oldpickListVal, ',');

                List<string> values = new List<string>();
                values = picklistvalDetail.split('#');                
                List<string> startDate = new List<string>();
                startDate = values[1].split('=');
                List<string> endDate = new List<string>();
                endDate = values[2].split('=');
                List<string> age = new List<string>();
                age = values[3].split('=');

                Integer fage = Integer.valueof(age[1]); 
                fage += date.valueof(datetime.valueof(startDate[1])).daysBetween(date.valueof(system.now()));
                string new_val = oldpickListVal+'#sd='+startDate[1]+ '#ed='+system.now()+' #'+'age='+fage ;                                  

                string finalString = obj.txtAreaval__c.replace(picklistvalDetail, new_val);           
                obj.txtAreaval__c = finalString ;                

                String pickListVal = obj.Stages__c;
                integer index = obj.txtAreaval__c.indexOf(pickListVal);

                if(index == -1){
                    obj.txtAreaval__c += pickListVal+'#sd='+system.now()+ '#ed='+' #'+'age=0,';                    
                }else{
                    picklistvalDetail = pickListVal+''+obj.txtAreaval__c.substringBetween(pickListVal, ',');

                    values = picklistvalDetail.split('#');

                    startDate = values[1].split('=');
                    endDate = values[2].split('=');
                    age = values[3].split('=');
                    fage = Integer.valueof(age[1]); 
                    fage += date.valueof(datetime.valueof(startDate[1])).daysBetween(date.valueof(datetime.valueof(endDate[1]))) ;
                    new_val = pickListVal+'#sd='+system.now()+ '#ed='+' #'+'age='+fage ;                  
                    finalString = obj.txtAreaval__c.replace(picklistvalDetail, new_val);           
                    obj.txtAreaval__c = finalString ;
                }
        }
     }   
}
```